# Is there a tool for drawing diagrams that connect equations?

Tags: r, matlab, workflow, diagram, flowchart

I don't know how to ask this question, actually. But I have a bunch of equations and constants and are all connected somehow. Let's say the following code in Matlab, for example:

```
R=8.314;
n=0.412;
a=4;
m=2;
S=10;
rho=1;
F=m*a;
P=F/S;
V=m/rho;
T=(P*V)/(n*R);
```

Is there a way that Matlab (or another language) returns you a diagram with the workflow, or something like that the figure?

[image]

Because I think any language needs to define each constant and equation in order, so I just want that order back

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That is a great question.  I have not seen anybody build it yet but it would be a great tool for teaching an "introduction to programming" class.

Comment: An interpreter like MATLAB would not build such a graph internally. Instead, each of the lines of code are executed in turn. If, when executing, a line references a variable that doesn't exist, the program has an error. So it is the programmer that mentally might make such a graph, but never the interpreter. On the other hand, an optimizing compiler (such as you'd have for C or C++) would build such a graph internally, as part of the code analysis used to optimize the order of operations, and to find redundant operations that don't need to be executed at all because the result is not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R use the igraph package as shown.  We assume that the input is the character string `Lines` shown in the Note at the end.

Read the input using `scan` (`scan` can also read from a file but to keep things self contained we use a character string as input here), remove empty components and strip out whitespace.

Extract the lhs and rhs of each line.

Then for each element of `rhs` get the variables in it giving list L.  Replace names with character labels of the form variable = expression.

Convert to data frame and from that to an igraph object `g` and plot.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)

V1 <- scan(text = Lines, sep = ";", what = "", quiet = TRUE)
V1 <- gsub(" ", "", V1[V1 != ""])

lhs <- sub("=.*", "", V1)
rhs <- sub(".*=", "", V1)

L <- setNames(lapply(rhs, function(x) all.vars(parse(text = x))), V1)
L <- lapply(L, function(x) ifelse(x %in% lhs, 
  paste0(x, "=", rhs[match(x, lhs)]), x))

g <- graph.data.frame(stack(L))
plot(g, vertex.color = NA, vertex.frame.color = NA)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Heatmap

Another possible representation is as a heatmap.  Get the adjacency matrix, optionally remove rows and columns which are all zero and plot.

```
m <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(g))
m <- m[apply(m > 0, 1, any), apply(m > 0, 2, any)] # rm 0 rows & cols
heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = 2:3, scale = "none", 
  margins = c(7, 7), cexCol = 1, cexRow = 1)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Bubble plot

Similar to the heat map we could draw a bubble plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stack(L), aes(ind, values)) + geom_point(cex = 10) + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Text

Another possibility is to just show the dependencies using text.  Display just `L` instead if you want to see components which have no dependencies as well.

```
L[lengths(L) > 0]
```

giving:

```
$`F=m*a`
[1] "m=2" "a=4"

$`P=F/S`
[1] "F=m*a" "S=10" 
 
$`V=m/rho`
[1] "m=2"   "rho=1"

$`T=(P*V)/(n*R)`
[1] "P=F/S"   "V=m/rho" "n=0.412" "R=8.314"
```

and inverting the list:

```
lapply(split(stack(L), stack(L)$values), function(x) as.character(x$ind))
```

giving:

```
$`a=4`
[1] "F=m*a"

$`F=m*a`
[1] "P=F/S"

$`m=2`
[1] "F=m*a"   "V=m/rho"

$`n=0.412`
[1] "T=(P*V)/(n*R)"

$`P=F/S`
[1] "T=(P*V)/(n*R)"

$`R=8.314`
[1] "T=(P*V)/(n*R)"

$`rho=1`
[1] "V=m/rho"

$`S=10`
[1] "P=F/S"

$`V=m/rho`
[1] "T=(P*V)/(n*R)"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
  R=8.314;
  n=0.412;
  a=4;
  m=2;
  S=10;
  rho=1;
  F=m*a;
  P=F/S;
  V=m/rho;
  T=(P*V)/(n*R);
"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, super helpful !. I tried, but the problem is that I have a lot of equations and constants, and some equations are huge, so it doesn't look well. So, I have two ideas to improve it:
1) in the figure I attached there is a kind of hierarchy of the formulas instead of randomness (as your figure). Is there a way to do that?
2) Is there a way to not write the equation and only the letter? for example, something like
               a-> F <- m 
. Regards,

Comment: If the two statements defining L are replaced with with `L <- setNames(lapply(rhs, function(x) all.vars(parse(text = x))), lhs)` then only the left hand sides will appear in the graph.

Comment: thank you! and for the hierarchy style? like, the constants at the top and the last equation T=(P*V)/(n*R) and the bottom?

Comment: igraph has documentation on how to manually specify the locations of the nodes.